# Flink delete old check point file

Tags: apache-flink

We are using file system as checkpoint state backend. Following is our setting:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(timeCharacteristic);
env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(Time.seconds(30).toMilliseconds());
env.enableCheckpointing(Time.seconds(30).toMilliseconds());
CheckpointConfig checkpointConfig = env.getCheckpointConfig();
checkpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend(props.getProperty("backendstate.path")));
```

This works fine during development, but as soon as we deploy to production, we found out that the checkpoint files quickly eat up disk space. I did an ls to one of the checkpoint directory and find that

```
chk-10   chk-104  chk-13  chk-18  chk-23  chk-28  chk-32  chk-37  chk-41  chk-46  chk-50  chk-55  chk-6   chk-64  chk-69  chk-73  chk-78  chk-82  chk-87  chk-91  chk-96 chk-100  ... hundreds of them
```

I am wondering if there is a way to delete the older chk-x files or we have to remove them manually?

Answer (score 1):

During deployment set the following property in the "*conf/flink-conf.yaml*" file to the maximum number of checkpoints you want to retain:

```
state.checkpoints.num-retained
```

Ideally, it should be more than 1, as it helps in recovering the job if the last checkpoint is corrupt.

For more information, check this out: [Config Options](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/checkpointing.html#related-config-options)

Answer (score 0):

Flink Job Manager must be able to access the nodes where the files are stored in order to delete them.
Either run all component in the same big machine or use a DFS as checkpoint storage.

Answer (score -1):

**You could try this**

```
CheckpointConfig config = env.getCheckpointConfig();
config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

The ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup mode configures what happens with externalized checkpoints when you cancel the job:

**ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION**: Retain the externalized checkpoint when the job is cancelled. Note that you have to manually clean up the checkpoint state after cancellation in this case.

**ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.DELETE_ON_CANCELLATION:** Delete the externalized checkpoint when the job is cancelled. The checkpoint state will only be available if the job fails.